# How can I update all fields except for 1 in one table, and update 1 input in a second table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravelcollective

I have a basic form for a candidate to fill out a Profile. One of the required fields is to upload a Resume, with a `resume_id` column, `int(11)`, in the `job_seeker_profiles` table. I have another table called Resumes, I thought I created the relationship properly but maybe I didn't. In my store method, everything in the form gets stored in the `job_seeker_profiles` table, except the resume. This gets stored in the resume's table, column called 'file' and the id from that record gets inserted into the `resume_id` column in the `job_seekers_profiles` table with the relationship I created earlier.
My store method is working perfectly, but my update method is not. It keeps inserting the actual filename inside of the `resume_id` column and nothing gets inserted into the Resumes table.

`AdminJobSeekerProfileController.php` file:

```
public function store(JobSeekerProfileCreateRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        $user = Auth::user();

        if($file = $request->file('resume_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('resumes', $name);

            $resume = Resume::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['resume_id'] = $resume->id;

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_one_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_one_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_two_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_two_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        if($file = $request->file('video_three_id')) {

            $name = time() . $file->getClientOriginalName();

            $name = preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $name);

            $file->storeAs('videos', $name);

            $video = Video::create(['file'=>$name]);

            $input['video_three_id'] = $video->id;

        }

        $user->jobSeekerProfile()->create($input);

        Alert::success('Your Profile has been created successfully!')->autoclose(5000);

        return redirect('/admin/job-seeker/profile');
    }

public function update(JobSeekerProfileCreateRequest $request)
    {

        $input = $request->all();

        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->jobSeekerProfile()->update($input);

        // Sweet Alert
        Alert::success('Your Profile has been updated successfully!')->autoclose(5000);

        return redirect('/admin/job-seeker/profile');
    }
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list'
```

Here is a screenshot of the full error, you can see on the screenshot it's trying to insert the name of the file uploaded into the `resume_id` column instead of an integer.

```
`resume_id` = Peter_Brewed_Resume_2020.docx,
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

your problem is `$request->all();`. You rarely want to allow users to arbitrarily put data into your DB. At minimum, you should specify which fields they are allowed to update. Better would be to scrub the data for appropriateness before committing to the DB.

You probably want something like

```
$request->only(['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'date_of_birth' ..... ]);
```

Also, you need to place your files the same way you did in the create method.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the `'files'=>true` on my edit Form:

```
{!! Form::model($jobSeekerProfiles, ['method'=>'PATCH', 'action'=> ['AdminJobSeekerProfileController@update', $jobSeekerProfiles->id], 'files'=>true]) !!}
```

Combined with using `$request->only` it is now working.